# HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests with WIKI pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, wikipedia, http-error

I am getting 429 error even though the quantity of pages visited by the script is not even 50. How can I tune the script to avoid the error. The User-Agent is the correct one for my Chrome browser. I have tried to put `time.sleep(10)` after the requests but that did not help. I am using jupyter notebook on Windows 10.

```
def get_wiki_list_italian_movies(year):
    import sys, bs4, requests, textwrap, , time, re
    from textblob import TextBlob
    
    p = r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Italian_films_of_' + str(year)
    list_wiki, list_wiki_links = [], []

    header = {'User-agent':
               'mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/86.0.4240.111 safari/537.36'}
   
    request = requests.get(p, headers = header)              
    time.sleep(10)

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable')
    
    for el in table:
        td = el.find_all('td')
        for t in td:
            i = t.find('i')
            if i:
                for a in i.find_all('a', href=True):
                    result = re.sub(r'[()]','',a['href'])
                    if '/w/index' in result:
                        list_wiki.append(re.sub(r'\(.*','',a['title']).strip() + ' ' + str(year))
                    else:
                        list_wiki_links.append('https://en.wikipedia.org'+result)

    for link in list_wiki_links:
        request = requests.get(link, headers = header)
        time.sleep(10)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
        i_list = soup.find_all('i')
        
        for i in i_list:
            b = i.find('b')
            if b:
                t= b.text
                if len(t) > 4 and TextBlob(t).detect_language() == 'it':
                    list_wiki.append(t.strip() + ' ' + str(year))
             
    return sorted(list(set(list_wiki)))

def movies_wiki_list(years_span):
    ll = []
    for year in years_span:
        ll += get_wiki_list_italian_movies(year)
        time.sleep(10)
    return ll

italian_movies_1932_1933 = movies_wiki_list(range(1932, 1934))
italian_movies_1932_1933
```

This is the error:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-6a4bc670faa6> in <module>
     53     return ll
     54 
---> 55 italian_movies_1932_1933 = movies_wiki_list(range(1932, 1934))
     56 italian_movies_1932_1933

<ipython-input-12-6a4bc670faa6> in movies_wiki_list(years_span)
     49     ll = []
     50     for year in years_span:
---> 51         ll += get_wiki_list_italian_movies(year)
     52         time.sleep(10)
     53     return ll

<ipython-input-12-6a4bc670faa6> in get_wiki_list_italian_movies(year)
     41             if b:
     42                 t= b.text
---> 43                 if len(t) > 4 and TextBlob(t).detect_language() == 'it':
     44                     list_wiki.append(t.strip() + ' ' + str(year))
     45 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py in detect_language(self)
    566         :rtype: str
    567         """
--> 568         return self.translator.detect(self.raw)
    569 
    570     def correct(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py in detect(self, source, host, type_)
     70         data = {"q": source}
     71         url = u'{url}&sl=auto&tk={tk}'.format(url=self.url, tk=_calculate_tk(source))
---> 72         response = self._request(url, host=host, type_=type_, data=data)
     73         result, language = json.loads(response)
     74         return language

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py in _request(self, url, host, type_, data)
     90         if host or type_:
     91             req.set_proxy(host=host, type=type_)
---> 92         resp = request.urlopen(req)
     93         content = resp.read()
     94         return content.decode('utf-8')

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    561             http_err = 0
    562         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
--> 563         result = self._call_chain(*args)
    564         if result:
    565             return result

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    753         fp.close()
    754 
--> 755         return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
    756 
    757     http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
try:
   urlpage=urllib.request.urlopen('url')

except:
   time.sleep(1)
   urlpage=urllib.request.urlopen('url')
```

This worked for me. Simply wait for some time after we get any error and try the same request again

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with wikipedia's API guide: [API:Etiquette](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette) and [API:FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:FAQ).

> There is no hard and fast limit on read requests, but we ask that you
> be considerate and try not to take a site down. Most sysadmins reserve
> the right to unceremoniously block you if you do endanger the
> stability of their site.
>
> If you make your requests in series rather than in parallel (i.e. wait
> for the one request to finish before sending a new request, such that
> you're never making more than one request at the same time), then you
> should definitely be fine. Also try to combine things into one request where you can (e.g. use multiple titles in a titles parameter instead of making a new request for each title

Thi suggests that you can fetch 50 pages per API request.

You can use [Data Dumps](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) as well if you need content offline (likely a little outdated which I think wouldn't be a problem in your case).

In case you hit any of the limits, you can handle errors & warnings in API calls using [these](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Errors_and_warnings) status messages.

Comment: Masquerading the bot as a browser is definitely not in line with the API etiquette, though (or common sense, really). It will screw up metrics, make it impossible for site admins to contact the owner etc.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 429 error is misleading. The error came not from the Wiki servers, but from
google. Google has a limit on the fee daily requests to textblob. But the googletrans
requests are free. So I have had to install googletrans and use it.

```
!pip install googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
```

And I have had to change

```
TextBlob(t).detect_language() == 'it'
```

to

```
 translator.detect(t).lang == 'it'
```

And now even when I use a larger search, i.e. a span of 10 years and not 2.
I get no 429 errors.